# jquery MVC4 receive JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send json data from my controller to my view when a specific action happens.

I used this on controller to send the data

```
[HttpGet] 
 public JsonResult JSONGetParking(int buildingID){

     return this.Json(
                          new
                          {
                              Result = (from obj in db.Parkings.Where(p => p.buildingID == buildingID) select new { ID = obj.ID, Name = obj.note })
                          }
                          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                       );
}
```

it works very good

on my script i used this:

**FloorScript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#buildingID').change(function () {
            alert("what is not");
            $.getJSON('JSONGetParking?buildingID=' + $('#buildingID').val(), function (data) {
                alert("afd");
                var items = " ";
                $.each(data, function (obx, oby) {
                    items += "<option value='" + oby.ID + "'>" + oby.Name + "</option>";
                });
                $('#parkingID').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
```

I have opened google chrome and I can see the request and the response like this:

[image]

i can see the **two** text that i alerted

However, on my selector, i just see `undefined value`

#### Html

```
<div id="editor-label">
        <select id="parkingID" name="parkingID"></select>
    </div>
```

I have added the jquery in this

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/FloorScript.js");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not looping on the correct variable.

You did this:

```
$.each(data, function (obx, oby) {
```

whereas you should do this:

```
$.each(data.Result, function (obx, oby) {
```

This is pretty visible in the Google Chrome screenshot you provided. As you can see the returned JSON has a property called `Result` which is the collection whereas you were looping over the `data` variable which is not an array - it's just a javascript object that has a property called `Result` which is the array you wanna be looping through.

Also I'd replace:

```
$.getJSON('JSONGetParking?buildingID=' + $('#buildingID').val(), function (data) {
```

with:

```
$.getJSON('JSONGetParking', { buildingID: $('#buildingID').val() }, function (data) {
```

and of course get rid of this hardcoded url over there and use an url helper to generate it, on the dropdown as an HTML5 data-* attribute:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.BuildingId, 
    Model.Buildings, 
    new { 
        id = "buildingID", 
        data_url = Url.Action("JSONGetParking") 
    }
)
```

and then inside the change event you can trivially easy retrieve this url and avoid hardcoding it (and of course taking the risk of breaking your code when you deploy it in IIS in a virtual directory or simply change the routing pattern of your application):

```
$('#buildingID').change(function () {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.getJSON(url, { buildingID: $('#buildingID').val() }, function (data) {
```

Alright, now the initial mess is tidied up.

Comment: It works when i make `Result`, however, i cant use the `url.action` because i want the jquery method to be called when another dropdown changed , am i right in that?

Comment: i accepted the answer, but please would you tell me about the other dropdown action?

Comment: This doesn't change anything in relation to the `data-url` attribute. It's the `#buildingID` dropdown that you are subscribing to the change event to, so it would make sense to put the data-url attribute on it. It is this dropdown that is making the AJAX call.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you mean. In my answer I placed the data-url on the `#parkingID` dropdown. That's a mistake. You should obviously put it on the `#buildingID` dropdown. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: you are the best one i have ever known, thak you very very very very very much

Answer (score 2):

use `data.Result` in your each loop

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#buildingID').change(function () {
            alert("what is not");
            $.getJSON('JSONGetParking?buildingID=' + $('#buildingID').val(), function (data) {
                alert("afd");
                var items = " ";
                $.each(data.Result, function (obx, oby) {
                    items += "<option value='" + oby.ID + "'>" + oby.Name + "</option>";
                });
                $('#parkingID').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps...